# Android downsides and expense of using if(file.exists()) for boolean variables?

Tags: java, android

Keep an open mind please :)

Android is used for a lot more than phones these days. My device has no end user access, they go through the cloud only and no battery.

I'm using 5 separate files that are either "Touched" by Android or downloaded from the cloud or destroyed from the cloud. These files provide workflow,hold options and share information for 4 separate apps, they are empty of course.
2 of the files come under if(file.exists()) every 15 seconds. Writing to SD is not an issue as they would be created or downloaded on avg several times per week.

What's the draw backs?

I cant see any, Timing it I get
start:1461796070918 finish:1461796070918 Total: 0ms
Every 10-15 of them take a ms

There is a fixed workload that the devices could never exceed.

Could using all of Google shared preferences and API's just introduce complexity and maybe even slow things down?

Comment: "Could using all of Google shared preferences and API's just introduce complexity and maybe even slow things down?" Have you tried timing Google Shared Preferences to see if things are or aren't slowed down?

Comment: Could you use a [`FileObserver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) to avoid needing to poll?

Comment: I would need to import more things across 4 apps and deal with maybe some possible unexpected outcomes with all that extra code, plus I think I would have to have all the apps run under the same user and get teared down all at once on crashes. Another option is an .ini file that I turn into an array.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner that is interesting, one thing "Warning: If a FileObserver is garbage collected, it will stop sending events." They can't throw my empty or nonexistent files in the garbage. Im not what the limits of a file.exists timeout are maybe the OS waits forever?

Comment: I cannot parse your comment, but I think you're asking if the garbage collection of the `FileObserver` results in the files being deleted: no, it's just a thing which watches the directory, it doesn't modify it at all.

Comment: Sorry yes I was just saying that FileObserver is not guaranteed to be kept running. file.exists seems more dependable.